# Get the Java program to read parenthesis, brackets, and curly braces

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program that verifies arithmetic expression are correctly formed. (For example: Correct form `"2 + (2-1)"`, incorrect form `")2+(2-1"`)

Once it's been verified, the program will compute the results.

At the moment, it can compute anything in parenthesis easily. But if there was a bracket involved (For example, `"2 [ 3 + (1) ]"`) The program verifies the expression is correct, but cannot calculate the results.

Here is the code I'm concerned about

```
void postfixExpression() {
    stk.clear(); // Re-using the stack object
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(expression);
    char current;
    // The algorithm for doing the conversion.... Follow the bullets
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String token = scan.next();

        if (isNumber(token)) 
        {
            postfix = postfix + token + " ";
        } else {
            current = token.charAt(0);

            if (isParentheses(current))
            {
                if (stk.empty() || current == Constants.LEFT_NORMAL) {

                    // push this element on the stack;
                    stk.push(new Character(current));
                } else if (current == Constants.RIGHT_NORMAL) {
                    try {

                        Character ch = (Character) stk.pop();
                        char top = ch.charValue();

                        while (top != Constants.LEFT_NORMAL) {
                            postfix = postfix + top + " ";
                            ch = (Character) stk.pop();
                            top = ch.charValue();
                        }

                    } catch (EmptyStackException e) {

                    }
                }
            } else if (isOperator(current))//
            {
                if (stk.empty()) {
                    stk.push(new Character(current));
                } else {
                    try {


                        char top = (Character) stk.peek();
                        boolean higher = hasHigherPrecedence(top, current);

                        while (top != Constants.LEFT_NORMAL && higher) {
                            postfix = postfix + stk.pop() + " ";
                            top = (Character) stk.peek();
                        }
                        stk.push(new Character(current));
                    } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
                        stk.push(new Character(current));
                    }
                }
            }// Bullet # 3 ends

        }
    } // Outer loop ends

    try {
        while (!stk.empty()) // Bullet # 4
        {
            postfix = postfix + stk.pop() + " ";
        }
    } catch (EmptyStackException e) {

    }
 }
```

I've created two methods: isBracket, and isCurly. At first, I thought the most appropriate solution is to just include the two method in the same manner as isParentheses. Like so:

```
 if (isParentheses(current))
            {
                if (stk.empty() || current == Constants.LEFT_NORMAL) {

                    // push this element on the stack;
                    stk.push(new Character(current));
                } else if (current == Constants.RIGHT_NORMAL) {
                    try {

                        Character ch = (Character) stk.pop();
                        char top = ch.charValue();

                        while (top != Constants.LEFT_NORMAL) {
                            postfix = postfix + top + " ";
                            ch = (Character) stk.pop();
                            top = ch.charValue();
                        }

                    } catch (EmptyStackException e) {

                    }
                }

            if (isCurly(current)) 
            {
                if (stk.empty() || current == Constants.LEFT_CURLY) {

                    // push this element on the stack;
                    stk.push(new Character(current));
                } else if (current == Constants.RIGHT_CURLY) {
                    try {

                        Character ch = (Character) stk.pop();
                        char top = ch.charValue();

                        while (top != Constants.LEFT_CURLY) {
                            postfix = postfix + top + " ";
                            ch = (Character) stk.pop();
                            top = ch.charValue();
                        }

                    } catch (EmptyStackException e) {


 if (isBracket(current)) 
            {
                if (stk.empty() || current == Constants.LEFT_SQUARE) {

                    // push this element on the stack;
                    stk.push(new Character(current));
                } else if (current == Constants.RIGHT_SQUARE) {
                    try {

                        Character ch = (Character) stk.pop();
                        char top = ch.charValue();

                        while (top != Constants.LEFT_SQUACRE) {
                            postfix = postfix + top + " ";
                            ch = (Character) stk.pop();
                            top = ch.charValue();
                        }

                    } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
```

But the program still would not consider the brackets and the braces (but it's still reading the parentheses fine.)

I'm not using the methods correctly from what I understand, but how can I use them appropriately?

Comment: Your example "2 [ 3 + (1) ]" doesn't contain curly brackets, only round and square brackets. Did you mean to use square brackets? Also, are nested brackets only ever round brackets nested within square brackets, or can square brackets be nested within round brackets?

Comment: "but cannot calculate the results" does the program calculate something wrong or do you get an exception? Did you checked whether 2 (3 + (1)) is working?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, or putting some `println`'s or something in your code to verify that the variables are what you think they're supposed to be or that the methods are returning what you think they should be returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea I thought of for taking a different approach to this problem.

You could split up the numbers and brackets into two different stacks, making it easier to ensure the expression is formed correctly.

At the beginning of the code, you could declare two stack variables:

```
Stack<Integer> numbers = new Stack<Integer>();
Stack<Character> operators = new Stack<Character>();
```

And then push operators and numbers accordingly.

This a very quick method I created that would demonstrate this implementation of using two `Stack` objects:

```
public double doCalculation(String input) throws DataFormatException {
    if (input == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    char[] characters = input.toCharArray();

    for (char character: characters) {
        try {
            // tries to push the number onto the number stack
            numbers.push(Integer.parseInt("" + character));

        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
            // if this is caught, this means the character is non-numerical
            operators.push(character);

        }
    }

    while (operators.size() > 0) {
        int i = numbers.pop();
        int j = numbers.pop();
        char operator = operators.pop();

        switch (operator) {
            case '+':
                numbers.push(j + i);
                break;
            case '-':
                numbers.push(j - i);
                break;
            case '*':
                numbers.push(j * i);
                break;
            case '/':
                numbers.push(j / i);
                break;
            case '^':
                numbers.push((int)(Math.pow(j, i)));
                break;
            default:
                throw new DataFormatException();
        }
    }

    return numbers.pop();
}
```

Just for fun:
If this code is added to the `catch` block before the non-numerical character is pushed to the stack, it will calculate the equation in terms of order of operations:

```
char top;
try {
    top = operators.peek();
} catch (EmptyStackException e2) {
    operators.push(character);
    continue;
}

if (getValue(character) > getValue(top)) {
    operators.push(character);
    continue;
} else {
    try {
        while (!(getValue(character) > getValue(operators.peek()))) {
            char operator;

            operator = operators.pop();

            int i = numbers.pop();
            int j = numbers.pop();

            switch (operator) {
                case '+':
                    numbers.push(j + i);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    numbers.push(j - i);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    numbers.push(j * i);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    numbers.push(j / i);
                    break;
                case '^':
                    numbers.push((int)(Math.pow(j, i)));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new DataFormatException();
            }

        }
    } catch (EmptyStackException e3) {
        operators.push(character);
        continue;
    }
```

Assuming a `getValue()` method is defined accordingly:

```
public int getValue(char character)
throws DataFormatException {
    switch (character) {
        case '+':
            return 1;
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '*':
            return 2;
        case '/':
            return 2;
        case '^':
            return 3;
        default:
            throw new DataFormatException();
    }

}
```